# JSON API response and ember model names

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

A quick question about the JSON API response key "type" matching up with an Ember model name.

If I have a model, say "models/photo.js" and I have a route like "/photos", my JSON API response looks like this

```
{
  data: [{
    id: "298486374",
    type: "photos",
    attributes: {
      name: "photo_name_1.png",
      description: "A photo!"
    }
  },{
    id: "298434523",
    type: "photos",
    attributes: {
      name: "photo_name_2.png",
      description: "Another photo!"
    }
  }]
}
```

I'm under the assumption that my model name should be singular but this error pops up

```
Assertion Failed: You tried to push data with a type 'photos' but no model could be found with that name
```

This is, of course, because my model is named "photo"

Now in the JSON API spec there is a note that reads "This spec is agnostic about inflection rules, so the value of type can be either plural or singular. However, the same value should be used consistently throughout an implementation."

So,

tl;dr Is the "Ember way" of doing things to have both the model names and the JSON API response key "type" both be singular? or does it not matter as long as they match?

Comment: JSON API serializer expects plural type. Where do you get error? Do you use `store.push`?

Comment: Yeah, I was building out a test response and using store.push. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON API serializer expects plural type. [Payload example from guides.](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html)

Since `modelNameFromPayloadKey` function singularizes key, it works with singular type:

```
// as is
modelNameFromPayloadKey: function(key) {
  return singularize(normalizeModelName(key));
}
```

but inverse operation `payloadKeyFromModelName` pluralizes model name and should be changed, if you use singular type in your backend:

```
// as is
payloadKeyFromModelName: function(modelName) {
  return pluralize(modelName);
}
```

It is important that the internal Ember Data JSON API format differs a bit from the one used by JSONAPISerializer. `Store.push` expects **singular** type, JSON API serializer expects **plural**.

From [discussion](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3794#discussion_r40203922):

"...ED uses camelCased attributes and singular types internally, regardless of what adapter/serializer you're using.

When you're using the JSON API adapter/serializer we want users to be able to use the examples available on jsonapi.org and have it just work. Most users never have to care about the internal format since the serializer handles the work for them.

This is documented in the guides, http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/
..."

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I should have read that bit of guide more carefully

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case, you might try [`pushPayload`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload) instead of [`push`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push). As the [documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/) suggests, it does some normalization; and in my case it covered the "plural vs. singular" problem.