# Saving a record sends the pluralized value for type attribute in PATCH request

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I am developing a simple TODO manager application in Ember using ember-data and JSONAPISerializer.

I have the following model which represents a task

***app/model/task.js***

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr ('string'),
    description: DS.attr ('string'),
    isComplete: DS.attr ('boolean')
});
```

The corresponding JSON data from back-end looks like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "task",
        "attributes": {
            "title": "Complete Ember TODO manager application",
            "description": "Build a simple Ember application for easily managing tasks",
            "is_complete": "false"
        }
    }
}
```

I have added editing support for task using the following controller.

***app/controllers/tasks/task.js***

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    isEditingTask: false,

    actions: {
        startEditTask() {
            this.set('isEditingTask', true);
        },
        doneEditTask(id) {
            this.set('isEditingTask', false);
            this.get('model').save();
        },
    }
});
```

When not in editing mode, an edit button is shown, which triggers the startEditTask action. When in editing mode a done button is show which triggers the doneEditTask action.

I have verified that the done button does generate a PATCH request.

The problem is that the JSON sent to the back-end has the type as **tasks** not **task**. Is this expected?

JSON sent with PATCH request is as follows

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "tasks",
        "attributes": {
            "title": "Allow editing of a task",
            "description": "Allow the user to change various properties of a task",
            "is_complete": "true",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's too late, but I've faced similar issue today and as far as I see based on these:

[JSON API response and ember model names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832065/json-api-response-and-ember-model-names)

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html

http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating

If endpoint is plural (eg. api/tasks), ember expects the type to be plural as well